# How to add link to each image in the slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used the code from "Why is this slideshow flickering?" which peter has given for one of your answers in the web-site, it works perfectly fine without any flicker, but my question is how do I add hyperlink to each of the images.
I have pasted the code for your reference

**Script**

```
(function() {     
  // ------     
  // ###### Edit these.     
  // Assumes you have images in path named 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc.     
  var imagePath = "images";     
  var lastImage = 5;         
  // How many images do you have?     
  var fadeTime = 4000;       
//  var index=1;
  // Time between image fadeouts.      
  // ------     
  // ###### Don't edit beyond this point.     
  // No need for outer index var     
  function slideShow(index) {                   
  var url = imagePath + "/" + index + ".jpg";                 
  // Add new image behind current image         
  $("#slideShow").prepend($("<img/>").attr("src",url));    
  // Fade the current image, then in the call back           
  //   remove the image and call the next image         
  $("#slideShow img:last").fadeOut("slow", function() {             
  $(this).remove();   
  setTimeout(function() {                  
  slideShow((index % lastImage) + 1)              
  }, fadeTime);         

  });     
  }     
  $(document).ready(function() {           
  // Img 1 is already showing, so we call 2    
   setTimeout(function() { slideShow(2)}, fadeTime);     
   delay(1000);
  }); })();  

</script>
```

Please Help.................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this:

```
$("#slideShow").prepend($("<img/>").attr("src",url));
```

Try adding this

```
$('#slideshow img').wrap('<a href="location" />');
```

You will need to change location to where you want the link to go

Comment: Thanks for answering me. the code which you have given will link all images to the same page, but I want different link for each image.

Answer (score 0):

On your line here:

```
$("#slideShow").prepend($("<img/>").attr("src",url));
```

(I really don't know JQuery or what ever this is, I do understand Javascript + HTML, however)

Could you add a:

```
.attr("onClick",JAVASCRIPTNAMEHERE)
```

To the end?

```
$("#slideShow").prepend($("<img/>").attr("src",url).attr("onClick","window.Navigate('www.Google.com')");
```

Comment: DalexL Thanks for answering me, the code which you have given above will link all the images to the same "www.google.com", but I need different links for each image.

Comment: How much of this language do you know?  Couldn't you use some form of simple if statement or read data from a file to determine the link?  My example was just and example.  Why send everybody to google :P (It is a great site though :3 )

Comment: I try Inserting the line which you said earlier it did not solve the problem. The image did not show up any links.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$("#slideShow").prepend($("<img/>").attr("src",url));
```

try using

```
$("#slideShow").prepend($("<a href='" + url + "'><img src='" + url + "' /></a>"));
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried the above code as follows       $("#slideShow").prepend($("<a href='" + www.google.com+ "'><img src='" + url + "' /></a>"));   , but unfortunately I  am not getting the link for the image.  help.............