# Slideshow href not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I am using http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/?whichScript=inline_slideshow jquery script

I want to give different different link in every images.

Looks like

```
<div class="imageSlideshowHolder" id="slideshow1">
    <a href="http://www.learnphp.in">
        <img src="../img.mysite.md/events/danceni/s01danceni.jpg" >
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img src="../img.mysite.md/events/danceni/s02danceni.jpg" >
    </a>
</div>
```

Above code the two images is sliding but last link `http://www.google.com` is working but `http://www.learnphp.in` not working.

How to change link with images?

Comment: Can't see any problem with the code you provide. Best guess is that you have a typo somewhere in your page, or JavaScript document. Check those, or post them here.

Comment: I just wanted to comment on the word 'DHTML'. Total blast from 2006.

Answer (score 2):

This is because they are putting two images one over another:

```
<div class="imageSlideshowHolder" id="imageSlideshowHolder">
            <img  src="http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/image-slideshow-4/images/image1.jpg" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com')">
            <img  src="http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/image-slideshow-4/images/image3.jpg" onclick="window.open('http://www.learnphp.in')">
</div>
```

But since the second image is always above first, here it will always open second link.

Either use some different library or change the library for your needs.

A mere google search result gave me following results:

http://wowslider.com/

http://bxslider.com/examples

http://www.slidesjs.com/

Comment: When i am adding one image with link the first image is showing second link, second image showing third link and the third image showing also third link. How could i fix?

Answer (score 2):

The slideshow works fine, the problem you have is that this javascript is not setup to provide an individual link to each image in the slideshow. As-is it won't work. I'm gonna see if I can crack ope the JS and modify it. If you rollover the image as it changes you will see that the url in your status bar never changes. Only one anchor tag is working and the content is getting switched out inside that element. You will need to assign a link via JS to each image as it changes.

(I see I was a few mins late on the answer) As the user below said, there are other image slideshow libraries that can do this for you with no modification.

This slideshow code is not optimized, you should look for another javascript slideshow that has the features you want. I found this one here on Stack O and there have been a few questions that debug and actually get the links working, here are the link:

[jQuery Slideshow](http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-slideshow.html)

[Add Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679853/how-to-add-link-to-each-image-in-the-slideshow/5683361#5683361)

And another:

[Link individual images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106537/how-to-link-individual-images-in-javascript-slideshow)

Comment: Check out the other links I provided, you don't want to mess with this code. It's messy. ALso there have got to be some good jQuery sliders that have link capabilities. I hate to say DO SOME MORE SEARCHING. But this one is garbage. Very hard to read because of the unnecessary naming conventions for one. jQuery is good at this. search "jQuery image sliders or use the links I provided and see what others used.